# How to force password to be typed before answering a call?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, password, call

Is there any way of asking for a password before picking up a call?

The iPhone's lock screen password works for not allowing people to access the iPhone main screen, but it allows anyone to pick up incoming calls.

Comment: Does any phone anywhere have this function?

Comment: I think it would be rather inconvenient to answer calls that way. To avoid redirection to voice mail the password must be rather short making it easy to guess/crack.

Answer (score 5):

No unfortunately this isn't a feature that is currently supported on iOS (I suppose it would be possible on a jailbroken device).

Answer (score 3):

To go with the answer(s) that mention that this is not currently available, it isn't likely to become available in the future, as, with Siri, one can send texts and place calls without unlocking the device, and outgoing connections are more likely to need securing than incoming connections.